# Concurrency with JPA, Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.5 and Spring 3.2.4 with JPA annotations.

I have the following method inside a service

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
    Foo foo = fooDao.findByName(fooName);
    if (foo == null)
        return null;
    foo.setBar(new Date());
    return fooDao.save(foo);
}
```

where fooDao is just an autowired `interface FooDao extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>`

If now multiple threads access the getFoo method the following happens:

```
Thread 1: Foo foo1 = getFoo("name1");
Thread 2: Foo foo2 = getFoo("name2");
```

but `foo1.getName() == foo2.getName() == "name2"` (or "name1"). This probably is a concurrency issue with the threads switching between the save and `select last_update_id`

I tried to add transaction isolation, but this doesn't help either. How can i prevent this? (`synchronized` on the method won't help either, obviously)

EDIT: my applicationContext:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...">
    <!-- ======== BoneCP ======== -->
    <bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!-- ... -->
    </bean>
    <!-- ======== SPRING ======== -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="foo.bar" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <ref local="mainDataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- ======== HIBERNATE / JPA ======== -->
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.cmr.cmair.server.db.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- the transactional advice -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allDaoMethods" expression="execution(* de.cmr.cmair.server.db.service.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allDaoMethods" />
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

The Foo class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "BAR")
    private Date bar;
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 225)
    private String name;

    // ... setters / getters
}
```

I just realized I don't use versioning / optimistic locking, but I'm not sure if this has any influence on this issue.

Comment: please include your spring configuration.

Comment: Why do you save an entity that already exists? What are you trying to do?

Comment: the JPADao's `.save` is actually a "saveOrUpdate" as far as I know. In the application i try to save a users login date. Also, the doc says "Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely."

I added my spring config.

Comment: please post your Foo class with its mapping

Comment: Using the primitive long as identifier is not really a good practice. Null values are needed to distinguish newly created instances.

I am just guessing now but can it be that the two rows exists with the same identifier in your DB? Maybe both have id:0?

Comment: no, both objects are embedded fine in the database (the actual code ran smooth for ~ 1 month but the amount of traffic increased => I first noticed the concurrency issues). These issues also don't always happen and when I wrap a `synchronized (lock) { fooService.getFoo("name1"); }` block around the request, it works, even with multiple threads. Another note: Inside the getFoo method both foos get "queried" i.e. `sysout(foo.getName())` leads to "name1", "name2". Thanks for the hint with the long / Long, will change that soon.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to have the optimistic locking or the record should be locked when user tries to edit the record.

Comment: are you shure optimistic locking helps here? As far as i unterstand, optimistic locking just helps preventing parallel edits on the same object.

Comment: Optimistic Lock prevents committing record updated by another user.